Style for consecutive links
I ran into this a while ago and just noticed it on a newer answer to a question recently migrated here. The problem is if you have multiple links in succession, it is impossible to tell that there are multiple links just by looking at the text. If you move your mouse over the links, then it shows up.
Is there a good way to have multiple links in succession? Or, is there a style change to links we can implement that will make it more clear that each word or phrase is a different link.
On Bruce Schneier's blog breaks in underlining makes it possible to see changes in links.

Your "newer answer" is older (and even migrated earlier) than the "while ago" one ;-)

@PaŭloEbermann, I realized that a while later, hehe. I hadn't seen that specific question so I assumed it was newer.

From the view of a reader, I don't think it is a good idea to link every word to somewhere else, if that somewhere isn't actually an explanation of the word used as the link – and then often it should be possible to have some non-linked words between.
The example from your linked answer:

Experts in quantum computing have been criticizing and debunking D-Wave's claims for years.  (Try clicking each of the last seven words, for examples.)   

This is just a list of links, each of them explaining/proving the whole sentence. I would write it like this:

Experts in quantum computing have been criticizing and debunking D-Wave's claims for years. [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

Of course, underlining the links can also help as a technical measure.

I like it. SE will automatically update the numbers too.

Good idea -- I like it.  Please feel free to edit that answer accordingly if you feel like it!
